# MAX function not bringing me my desired results

Tags: dependency-injection

I Have 4 columns I am interested in creating a list. We collected weekly data from our third party vendor. We sort it by the DataCollection week. They do not always submit this data. So, there will be times where a Vender submitted one week but not the next. I need to have a running total of total enrollments by the collection week broken down by the name. I did the MAX function but that only gives me the latest date in the whole table, I want the max for each districts individual date. How do I accomplish this so that say, if the latest week is 2/21/2020 for Name A, and the latest week for Name b was 2/14/2020, I can have both dates and enrollment totals, because as it stands I get only the max date which is 2/21/2020 but the names of those other districts that submitted the data are not coming back.
The code below is what I have.

`SELECT DATACOLLECTIONWEEK, NAME,DISTSCH,TOTALENROLLMENTS
FROM DB.SCHEMA.TEST
WHERE datacollectionweek = (SELECT MAX(datacollectionweek) 
                            FROM DB.SCHEMA.TEST)`

Comment: Please use appropriate tags. This has nothing to do with `dependency-injection`, and instead with some kind of database. Please **[edit]** the question and tag the exact RDBMS: e.g. Oracle, MySQL, SQL Server, etc. Also, please include sample table data along with current results + desired results.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATACOLLECTIONWEEK, NAME,DISTSCH,TOTALENROLLMENTS
FROM DB.SCHEMA.TEST as DB1
WHERE DB1.datacollectionweek = (SELECT MAX(datacollectionweek) 
                                FROM DB.SCHEMA.TEST AS DB2
                                WHERE DB1.NAME = DB2.NAME)
```